# Disable toggle button click function, if button in active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, togglebutton

I just created mvc 4 application. Here the view of a table of that project.

I want to disable clickable function currently active button

For example:

**disable click function of first row Active button , enable click function for Inactive button**

and

**disable click function of 2nd row Inactive button , enable click function for Active button**

likewise rest of it.

[image]

Here the current cshtml code for this table view button function

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle" id="btn-toggle"> 


     @if (item.Status == true)
     {
<button class="btn btn-xs active btn-primary" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true" >Active</button>                       
<button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false" >Inactive</button>

    }

    else
   {
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "true" >Active</button>                       
<button class="btn btn-xs inactiveColor btn-primary active" data-HEI_ID = "@item.HEI_ID" data-status = "false" >Inactive</button>

  }                        

  </div>
```

This is JavaScript code snippet to handle this buttons

```
   $('.btn-toggle').click(function () {

        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');
        //if ($(this).find('btn-primary').toggleClass('active')) {
        //$(this).prop('disabled', true);

        //}
        if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').size() > 0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');

        }
        if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size() > 0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');

        }
        if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size() > 0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');

        }
        if ($(this).find('.btn-info').size() > 0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');

        }

        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');

});
```

Comment: So what is your actual question. Is something not working?

Comment: currently it stay as both active/inactive buttons clickable, I want to disable active one

Comment: Do you mean something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/975uzh9n/1/)?

Comment: exactly , thats What I want

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:not()`:

```
$('.btn-toggle').find('button:not(.active)').click(function () {
```

---

The above one is binding a click event on the buttons which does not have `.active` css class in the parent div `.btn-toggle`

Where i am assuming* that you have `.active` css class in the css which turns the button in green background color.

<sub>*:You can replace it with your active class.</sub>

Comment: now active button disabled , your solution 50% right but to see actual button status I should refresh page , previously it showed without page refresh when I switch button state,

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your button groups in a container to make it easier to use relative selectors

```
<div>
    <button class="inactive">Active</button>
    <button disabled="disabled">InActive</button>
</div>
```

and then use the following script

```
$('button').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).closest('div').children('button').toggleClass('inactive');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).siblings('button').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[Refer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/975uzh9n/1/)

Comment: Do I assume that _"exactly , thats What I want"_ is not really what you wanted after all?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove click event from active buttons on DOM load event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.active').unbind('click');
}
```